# Hezbollah in South America

Tags: south-america, hezbollah, lebanon

Are Hezbollah active in South America? If so what is the connection? Why and what are they doing so far away from their host country?

Only yesterday U.S. State Secretary Mike Pompeo spoke about the presence of the Iranian proxy's presence in Latin America.

Source:
https://www.aa.com.tr/en/americas/hezbollah-is-real-threat-in-south-america-pompeo/1709602#

Comment: Pompeo claims Hezbollah is active in Venezuela, without much detail. It sounds to me like "axis of evil" reloaded. See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Funding_of_Hezbollah#Venezuela for some details.

Comment: Hezbollah has raised funds in South America via the Lebanese community there. There are allegations of large scale drug smuggling and money laundering. In the 1990s, Hezbollah conducted major terrorist attacks against Jewish and Israeli targets in Latin America. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hezbollah#Latin_America_operations

Comment: @Colin Maybe you would like to do some more research and turn this into a real answer?

Comment: Have you read [The secret backstory of how Obama let Hezbollah off the hook](https://www.politico.com/interactives/2017/obama-hezbollah-drug-trafficking-investigation)?

Comment: [Trade-based money laundering: overview and policy issues](https://fas.org/sgp/crs/misc/R44541.pdf). [PDF]

Answer (score -1):

there is an active Lebanese community in South America, due to Lebanon recent history (Civil war) and lack of resources Lebanese community exist all around the world. and their political dogmas goes with them.

as Venezuela's government is in opposition to the US policy, it got closer to Iran, and as such, trying to smear them with link to Hezbollah which they invested a lot of Demonetization propaganda pays dividends

even if  Hezbollah is active in south America, it has political army (with members in the Lebanese government)which act like any other political party gathering supporters et al